# How to type math in KonvaJS? (Integrate MathQuill or similar)

Tags: konvajs

I'm wondering if there's a way to type math in KonvaJS.

I made a research and I found this formula editor, but it seems that there's no way to convert it into Canvas: [MathQuill](http://mathquill.com/)

Is there any way to integrate this script into KonvaJS? Or any other idea to achieve this?

Comment: That may be a super weird solution, but you can try to convert generated DOM of MathQuill into image (you can find libraries for that). Then use that image for `Konva.Image`.

Comment: I was thinking about something like that. I think that is the best approach for now. Thanks! If I find a better solution I'll post it here.